# Primes above the distant prime neighbors

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\ \mathbb P\ $ be the set of all natural primes. Pair $\ (p\ q)\ $ are ***prime
neighbors*** $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow$
$$ \{x\in\mathbb Z: p\le x\le q\}\cap\mathbb P\,\ =\,\ \{p\,\ q\} $$
Prime $\ x\in\mathbb P\ $ is said to be ***above neighbors***
$\ (p\ q)\,\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow$
$$ 2\cdot p+1\ \le\ x\ \le\ 2\cdot q-1.$$

**EXAMPLE:** There are no primes above prime neighbors $\ (101\ 103),\ $ i.e.
$$ \{x\in\mathbb P:\ 2\cdot101+1\ \le\ x\ \le\ 2\cdot103-1\}\ \cap\ \mathbb P
       \quad =\quad \emptyset $$

---

---

---

Prime neighbors $\ (p\ q)\ $ are said to be ***distant*** $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $
for every prime neighbors $\ (x\ y)\ $ such that $\ x<p\ $ we have $\ y-x<q-p$.

**QUESTION** (a conjecture):   There is a prime above every pair of distant prime neighbors.

Comment: Have you numerically confirmed the conjecture?

Comment: You are asking if there can be a prime gap larger than 2M with a start below 2p+1 when M is a maximal prime gap starting at p. Seems unlikely! Like a lot of questions about prime gaps, you'll probably be stuck with conjectures about asymptotics. See http://primerecords.dk/primegaps/maximal.htm for computational records.

Comment: @ZackWolske, indeed, such q's occur routinely in small bunches: "all" "almost all", "infinitely many", ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably true, and will almost certainly be hard to prove. The prime neighbours satisfying your hypothesis grow more quickly than one might expect, and the $p$ are listed in A002386. The corresponding gaps $q-p$ also grow more quickly than one might expect, and are listed in A005250. So an automatic search is easy to do, and shows that the number of primes "above" is also growing. In particular, your question has a positive answer for primes up to $10^{10}$.

Comment: Dave, thank you for your answer and for your good nature effort.